# Describe $\text{Jac}(n\mathbb Z)$ in terms of the prime factorization of $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal of the commutative ring $R$ and define 
$\mathrm{Jac}(I)$ to be the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R$ that contain $I$.

> Let  $n > 1$ be an integer. Describe $\text{Jac}(n\mathbb Z)$ in terms of the prime factorization of $n$. (in ring $\mathbb Z$)

I have no idea how to start it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints :

- In $\mathbb Z$, an ideal $I\ne ${$0$} is a prime ideal if and only if it is a maximal ideal, if and only if $I=p\mathbb Z$ for some prime number $p$.
- An ideal $I=m\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Z$ contains $n\mathbb Z$, if and only if $m|n$
- Jac $n\mathbb Z=m\mathbb Z$, where $m$ is the product of the prime factors of $n$.

Comment: I don't understand why Jac $\mathbb Z_n=\mathbb Z_m$.

Comment: Jac $n\mathbb Z$ is the intersection of all ideals $p\mathbb Z$ with $p|n$ and $p$ prime.